# Haskell custom datatype with parameter

Tags: haskell

I have a custom data type as follows:

```
 data MyType a = Nothing
             | One a
```

The idea is to have a function that return the data type.  For example,

`func (One Char)` should return `Char` -- return the data type

I tried to implement `func` as follow:

```
func :: MyType a -> a
func (One a) = a
-- don't worry about Nothing for now
```

The code compiled but when I tried to run `func (One Char)` it gives me an error: `Not in scope: data constructor ‘Char’`

What is going on?

Comment: You cannot use `Char` like that, because `Char` is a *type*, not a *value*. In `func (One ...)`, you need to replace the dots by a *value* (of any type), e.g. `func (One 'a')`.

Answer (score 2):

Try `func (One "Hello")` it will work.

The reason is that Haskell thinks you are trying to give it a *data-constructor* because you wrote a upper-case `Char` so just give it some real value ;)

BTW: In case you really want to give the *type* `Char`: that's in general not possible in Haskell as you need a dependent-type caps (see [Idris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idris_(programming_language)#Dependent_types) for example).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried func (One "Hello") and it gives me back "Hello"? I expected it returns something like String? Looks like I need to modify func?

Comment: oh - no sorry it's not that easy - you can use something like http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Typeable.html (it's a bit like the runtime-type-information you get with Java and .net) but overall see my addition above

Comment: what are you trying to do with this? Maybe we can help with that instead?

Comment: um...to simplify it, what I am trying to do is to read a string, gets the prefix of the string which matches certain pattern, then extract this part of matched string and show it as (a,string), where a is a datatype...um...maybe I should understand my problem better.

Answer (score 1):

That's not really how haskell works. `Char` is a type, so we can write

```
func :: MyType Char -> Char
```

meaning that we expect the "something" of `MyType` to be a Char.

Checking what type an argument has is probably valid in something like Java, but is not the way functional programming works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's much chance you *really* want this with your current level of understanding of Haskell (it's a stretch for me, and I've been at it a while), but if you really really do, you can actually get something pretty close.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-} --might as well

-- I renamed Nothing to None to avoid conflicting with Maybe.
-- Since we're using DataKinds, this creates not only a type
-- constructor MyType and data constructors None and One,
-- but also a *kind* MyType and *type* constructors None and
-- One.
data MyType a = None | One a

-- We can't make a *function*, func, to take One Char and
-- produce Char, but we can make a *type function* (called
-- a type family) to do that (although I don't really know
-- why you'd want this particular one.
type family Func (a :: MyType k) :: k
type instance Func (One a) = a
```

Now if we write

```
Prelude> '3' :: Func (One Char)
```

GHCi is perfectly happy with it. In fact, we can make this type function even more general:

```
type family Func2 (a :: g) :: k where
  Func2 (f a) = a
```

Now we can write

```
'c' :: Func2 (One Char)
```

but we can also write

```
'c' :: Func2 (Maybe Char)
```

and even

```
'c' :: Func2 (Either Char)
'c' :: Func2 ((Either Int) Char)
```

But in case you think anything goes,

```
'c' :: Func2 (Maybe Int)
```

or

```
'c' :: Func2 Char
```

will give errors.